# AWS Distributor - How to create a flexible SSM Distributor Package?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

I have created an AWS Systems Manager Distributor Package. It is very specific to my environment. I would like to generalize it. In the **install.ps1** file I currently have:

```
msiexec /i mymsi.msi PARM1="TEST-1" PARM2="360fc9f925458cd2039a299" /qn /L*v myinstall.log
```

I would like to generalize this such that my **install.ps1** file would look something like this:

```
msiexec /i mymsi.msi var1="{MYPARM1}" var2="{MYPARM2}" /qn /L*v myinstall.log
```

Then when performing the distribution, I would include MYPARM1, MYPARM2 as part of the distribution. This would allow a public distribution of the product to various customers who are provided values for MYPARM1, MYPARM2

*I think these parameter values would go in the "Additional Arguments" section when using the AWS Console to Install the Distributor*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This required reverse-engineering a third-party add-in:

1-within the *.ps1 files parameters are read. The parms must have a prefix of SSM

Example **install.ps1**:

```
$MYPARM1=$env:SSM_MYPARM1
$MYPARM2=$env:SSM_MYPARM2
msiexec /i mymsi.msi var1=$MYPARM1 var2=$MYPARM2 /qn /L*v myinstall.log
```

2 - When supplying **Additional Arguments** to the AWS portal, provide the following

```
{
    "SSM_MYPARM1": "value1",
    "SSM_MYPARM2": "value2"
}
```

When the ***.ps1** file is invoked, the values are read from **Additional Arguments** and can be used in the script.

Comment: This is documented now, but at the time of writing, the documentation suggests you pass in a mapping, while in fact you pass in said mapping json encoded to a string.  If you're using the console then that's what you are doing to start with, but if you're cloud forming, or making API calls, then remember to json encode what you're passing in.